# I am trying to display columns from a view using the below mentioned query but its shows the following query

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, view

create view dept30 as 
select e.empno, e.ename, e.deptno from emp e where e.deptno=30;

--view created

select * from [dept30];

--error

ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 93 Column: 15

Comment: * a correction in the title, ".....it shows the following error"

Comment: You can correct the title yourself. Do you see the little `edit` link, right under your post? Click it and correct the title.

Comment: While you edit your post, look also at the little tags under your question. Delete the `MySQL` tag, since obviously you are using Oracle Database, not MySQL. (You may also delete the `database` tag since your question is really specific to Oracle, not to any other database product.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're selecting from `[dept30]` and not from `dept30`. Oracle doesn't use `[ ... ]` around table and column names. Just like in your view definition, where you said, correctly, `from emp`, not `from [emp]`.

Comment: and does oracle sql use square brackets?

Comment: @palakarora I don't think so.

Comment: This would be correct for Oracle also. The error message, ORA-#####, shows the OP uses Oracle database, not MySQL.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the answer a bit, I hope you don't mind Dale; if you do, please feel free to edit again to your satisfaction.